# How do I save text content in a pdf. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have some PDF files that I need to read their content and save to a table in the Oracle database, I would need some method or procedure to do this.
Note: pdf is not an image.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  In older versions you could probably use Oracle Multimedia but that's been retired in 19c so it's probably not wise to build new functionality using it.  It would likely make more sense to get a Java library that reads PDF files, load that in the database, and write a Java stored procedure to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle Text.

From [Rob van den Berg's blog: PDF to plain text, please](https://vxcompany.com/2020/07/23/pdf-to-plain-text-please/):

*(This is untested as I don't have an Oracle instance to hand at the moment.)*

Create the `userfilterpdftotext.sh` script in the `$ORACLE_HOME/ctx/bin` folder:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/pdftotext -enc "UTF-8" -q "$1" "$2"
```

Set up the Oracle Text preferences needed:

```sql
begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference
  ( preference_name => 'PDF_Filter_Preference'
  , object_name     => 'USER_FILTER'
  );
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute
  ( preference_name => 'PDF_Filter_Preference'
  , attribute_name  => 'COMMAND'
  , attribute_value => 'userfilterpdftotext.sh'
  );
  ctx_ddl.create_policy
  ( policy_name     => 'PDF_Filter_Policy'
  , filter          => 'PDF_Filter_Preference'
  );
end;
/
```

Then, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pdf_documents (
  binary_pdf BLOB,
  plain_text CLOB
);
```

You can run:

```sql
declare
  cursor c_doc
  is
  select  doc.binary_pdf
  ,       doc.plain_text
  from    pdf_documents doc
  for update of doc.plain_text;
  r_doc c_doc%rowtype;
begin
  open c_doc;
  fetch c_doc into r_doc;
  while c_doc%found
  loop
    ctx_doc.policy_filter
    ( policy_name => 'PDF_Filter_Policy'
    , document    => r_doc.binary_pdf
    , restab      => r_doc.plain_text
    , plaintext   => TRUE
    , format      => 'BINARY'
    );
    update pdf_documents doc
    set    doc.plain_text = r_doc.plain_text
    where  current of c_doc;    
    fetch c_doc into r_doc;    
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```